# How to configure an ehcache at a different server in spring backed application

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have a business critical application in JAVA and I do not want to have ehcache on same server. I want to use a different server for the caching. If a data is updated in master application, data should be refreshed or marked dirty in cache server. Application server and cache server both are java applications. I do not want to use web service or restful API due to network overhead. Can it be done via RMI or EJB. Also, can it be configurable

- if a data is updated in application server, cache should be updated (any annotation on method)?
- Any configuration to tell application server get method that data needs to fetch from cache server first?

Comment: You don't want to mess with that yourself as managing state properly is a job on its own. I would argue that the overhead of EJB is far more higher than the use of a proper restful API by the way. Cache implementations have such infrastructure check BigMemory from Tereacotta or Hazelcast.

Comment: I'd suggest using [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and [JMX with Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/cache-server#Load-Balancers) and possibly a load balancer to handle the network IO.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is going to be similar to Stéphane Nicoll's comment.

Don't do this yourself!

The problem you describe has been resolved in third party specialised frameworks such as Ehcache BigMemory, Hazelcast, Infinispan and others. Also some of the abstractions you want can be found in Spring's caching solution.

However these solutions will have different impact on your implementation and will force you to revise some of the statements you make.